# How to center with javascript an element on y?

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

I am trying to make a sticky banner witn html and css and js. My html is this

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(ev) {


  var distanceToTop = container.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if (container.getBoundingClientRect().top >= document.documentElement.scrollTop - screen.height + 400) {
    sticky.style.top = "100px"
  } else {
    sticky.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop - screen.height + 400 + "px";

  }

});
```

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky"></div>
</div>
```

I would want  when i scroll the window the stocky div to be center on y axis and when the distance between container and top of the page is less then 200px the two divs to be attached.
Can anyone to give me a clue?

Comment: You write "top of the page is less then 200px the two divs to be attached". Perhaps you mean 100px? Because div container height is 100px.

Comment: ok 100....no problem

Comment: Div container, which is 100pixels parent. position: sticky; will not be received, but only position: fixed;

Comment: hey...so container - position sticky and sticky position fixed?

Comment: with your code, the sticky cannot be done, tk. parent container is 100 pixels high. the sticky needs space.

Comment: i think i understand . i put both divs in another div with high height <div style="position: relative; height: 6200px">
<div class="container"></div>
 <div class="sticky"></div>
</div>

Comment: you didn't fully understand me. for the `position: sticky` to work (for blue block), you need to set the parent container `.container` to a significant height.

Comment: I want to help you. How are you doing? Have you redesigned the html structure?

Comment: yes. thans alot